# Makefile.inc: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, makefile, autotools

I don't have much experience with makefiles, but I am trying to compile and run the program "hdf5ToMds.c" found on this Github repository: https://github.com/MDSplus/mdsplus/tree/alpha/hdf5

My steps towards using the Makefile.in in the folder were as follows:

1. autoscan
2. mv configure.scan configure.ac
3. aclocal
4. autoheader
5. autoconf
6. ./configure
7. make

Now when I run the make I get the error:

```
Makefile:1: Makefile.inc: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'Makefile.inc'.  Stop.
```

Am I missing something obvious? I'm not very familiar with this whole process of getting the code from Github and having to make it. I do have the entire repository cloned, just in case that's relevant.

Comment: Eh ... Why don't you follow the description in the readme file? No need to build a configure file ... it's already there..

Comment: You can't start at that folder. Go one directory up and run ./configure , then run make.  That top directory also have README files that you should read.

Comment: After I run ./configure and then run make, I get the error "no specified makefile found". This is what is throwing me off. @nos Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Perhaps ./configure did not succeed.

Comment: I suspect that without the `makefile.inc` being located in the (so called) top_builddir that you will not be able to build this application except by hand.  Amongst other things, lt looks like the processes you used need to be run from that same top_builddir.

Comment: I noticed several header files being `#included` in the source files that are not on my system (ubuntu linux 16.04)  Do you have all those header files?